# gorm relations does not appear in database after migrations

Tags: sql, go, one-to-many, go-gorm

I am using gorm as an ORM in my project, I have some models that are related to togethe.
But after migration, I see no relation in the database!

these are my models:

```
type User struct {
    ID            uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `gorm: "primary_key"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time
    ArchivedAt    time.Time
    ReferenceId   int            `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Thank         []Thank        `gorm: "foreignkey:ID"`
}

type Thank struct {
    ID          uint   `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt   string `gorm: "primary_key"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    ArchivedAt  time.Time
    ReferenceId int
    CreatorId   int   `gorm:foreignkey:ReferenceId`
    Description string `gorm:"type:varchar(200)"`
    SentToUsers postgres.Jsonb
}
```

after migrations of them, I don't see the creator_id column in the thank table and also thanks in the user table.

Answer (score 1):

I got this result that I can use **Add Foreign Key** function in gorm.
In my case it can be:

```
    db.Model(&Thank{}).AddForeignKey("creator_id", "users(reference_id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

for add relation between user and thank table in database.